# glload error in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4, mingw, mingw32

Trying to create an OpenGL application using glload in Qt, I tested sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <glload/gl_all.h>
#include <glload/gll.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    glload::LoadFunctions();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, it stop working. The debug error is

> can't run ": The requested operation requires elevation.

The build command is

> qmake.exe C:\Users\Benbroher\test\test.pro -r -spec win32-g++  "LIBS+=-lglloadD"  "LIBS+=-lopengl32"

My Qt is 4.8.1, and glsdk is 0.4.4. 
I am running a 64-bit version of windows7, and it happened in a 32-bit version of winXP.

What might cause this and how do I solve it?

Comment: Where do you create your GL context?

Comment: Since there is nothing Qt specific at all about your question, I'm assuming you meant "Qt Creator" (the IDE) rather than Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load OpenGL functions until you have created a valid OpenGL context and made it current. [The documentation is very clear on this](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/group__module__glload.html#glload_initialization).

Comment: thank you.It is my fault.I didn't read the documentation careful before. I think that "Initialize OpenGL and bind the context" is not necessary and glload::LoadFunctions() must be the first in code.

Comment: Really? That solved your problem regarding the required elevation? Quite surprising, but good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Where's your QApplication object instance? Without this, most of Qt is nonfunctional.

Comment: Though I'm assuming this is not much of a Qt issue. I guess the OP is referring to Qt Creator (IDE) rather than Qt itself. :s

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your immediate problem has nothing to do with either Qt or OpenGL. (Though the points made about both Qt and OpenGL in the other answers are valid. Take them into account).

My assumption is that the lack of an embedded manifest is your main issue. Given that you're on windows, I assume it's using qmake/mingw, which might mean that there is no automatic embedding of a manifest.

This can sometimes result in Windows assuming that the application needs to be run with administrator privileges. Especially for some particular application names. Perhaps you can inform us what your application (the exe) is called. For now I assume this to be the issue.

For information on how to embed a standard manifest, have a look at [this excellent blog entry](http://blog.strixcode.com/2010/08/embedding-application-manifest-and.html).